# display realtime CPU usage in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am wondering about the possibility of displaying *CPU load percentage* in R shiny app.  I am using Linux x64, if it matters.

Comment: `readLines("/proc/loadavg")`? (linux only, not win, not sure about mac.) (This has nothing to do with shiny and all about OS interaction from R.)

Comment: To re-run this code periodically in shiny you can use `invalidateLater`

Comment: altogether it is a complete answer, kiitos :)